# accepts_nested_attributes_for with foreign_key option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have 3 models associated each other by ActiveRecord association on RoR. 
I'm trying to create child instances in ParentsController#create action.
But I get an error that child instance cannot save without a parent.

Model

```
Class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, :through => :middles #, :class_name => 'Parent'
  has_many :p_has_childs, :foreign_key => 'p_id'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :p_has_childs
end

Class PHasChild < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :foreign_key => 'p_id'
  validates_presence_of :parent, :child
end

Class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :p_has_childs
  has_many :parents, :through => :middles, :class_name => 'Parent'
end
```

View

```
@parent.form_for do |f|
  @parent.p_has_childs.each do |p_has_child|
    f.fields_for :p_has_childs, p_has_child do |p_f|
      p_f.select :child_id
    end
  end
  f.submit
end
```

I tried accepts_nested_attributes_for method and worked well if Class PHasChild has parent_id and child_id (and use ParentHasChild class) but I need to use p_id instead_of parent_id.
How can I use foreign_key option of belongs_to association?

Comment: I guess you should give `class_name => 'Parent'` in this line too `has_many :childrens, :through => :middles` in the `Parent` model.

Comment: I tried but no change.

Comment: First thing first.. there is nothing called childrens.. so replace it with `children` everywhere.And secondly, what is middles? Do you have a different model for it? or are you pointing to `PHasChild` model?